# Detect duration of phone call

Tags: ios, swift

1. I make and receive a phone call
2. After the phone call, I need to mark the duration of the call and save this value.

I installed CallKit framework, but I didn't find how to detect the duration of conversations.

Is it possible to detect the duration of phone calls?

Comment: I don't think so.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think use need CallKit help, you can use Date here. All you need to do is,

```
let startDate = Date() // on call start
let endDate = Date() // on call end

let duration = endDate.timeIntervalSince(startDate) as Double
print("duration: \(duration)")
```